# How do I get the position of a parent div containing an iframe in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the jquery index() position of a div containing an iframe where an event has happened. All in the same domain.

```
<div class="seBox">
    <div class="editBox">
        <input type="hidden" id="textarea1___Config" style="display:none">
        <iframe id="textarea1___Frame" src="/3rdparty/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=textarea1&amp;Toolba‌​r=SimpleToolbar" width="100%" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; background-color: transparent; background-image: none; width: 100%; height: 200px;"></iframe>
        <textarea name="textarea1" class="field-style seItem-input" cols="45" style="display: none;"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment my code for the event function, which doesn't work, looks like this:

```
alert($(this, window.parent.document).closest('.seBox').index());
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: We will need more info to be helpful.  Your HTML for starters.

Comment: <div class="seBox"><div class="editBox" >
<input type="hidden" id="textarea1___Config" style="display:none">
<iframe id="textarea1___Frame" src="/3rdparty/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html?InstanceName=textarea1&amp;Toolbar=SimpleToolbar" width="100%" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; background-color: transparent; background-image: none; width: 100%; height: 200px;"></iframe>
<textarea name="textarea1" class="field-style seItem-input" cols="45" style="display: none;"></textarea>
</div></div>

Comment: This is the basic code around it for context... There are multiple blocks of these divs, so I am just after the index of the div containing the iframe with the event.

Comment: I think your question might still need some work. You can edit the question instead of the comments. Where are you calling the `alert` . What do you mean by iframe with the event? Is the iframe doing something that you want to register in it's parent?

Comment: Thanks for your help - I have found a way of getting the DOM info without needing to look at the iframe, so my question is now redundant. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are exactly trying to achieve, but maybe you may tackle this problem with [delegated event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Try this (untested) :

```
$( 'div.seBox' ).on( 'myEvent', 'div.editBox', function( event ){
  var index = $(event.delegateTarget).index(event.currentTarget)
});
```

The event should :

- bubble up from the iframe to the `.seBox`
- trigger the delegated event handler
- inside the handler, `event.delegateTarget` should be the particular `.seBox` element that receives the event, and `event.currentTarget` should be the `div.editBox` (I'm not sure about this last one, the doc is not pretty clear on this and i always confuse it with `event.target`)

Comment: Thanks for your help - I have found a way of getting the DOM info without needing to look at the iframe, so my question is now redundant. Thanks again.